# Do build warnings affect the iOS app store approval process?

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval

When an app is undergoing the app store approval process, do the people at Apple check the warnings in your project, or do they only check for errors?

e.g. I have this warning on a lot of my NIB files:

> Unsupported Configuration: Title set but using a system Identifier (These attributes are mutually exclusive; the Title will be ignored)

Will this be a reason for Apple to reject my app for the app store?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an app store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apple won't check for warnings in your project, because they can't. They don't get the source code to your app, only the compiled binary and supporting files. So long as you follow the rules, you should be fine.

As for the specifics of your question: I very much doubt it, but nevertheless, you should definitely aim for a project which compiles without warnings, just as a general programming practice.

Comment: A good answer, but the specific warning James mentions *might* actually be discoverable using the final build artifacts, as NIB files contain XML.