# The app references non-public selectors in Payload/<AppName>.app/<AppName>

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I built an app to deliver it to the AppStore but the validation process throw this error:

```
The app references non-public selectors in Payload/<AppName>.app/<AppName>: categories, content, contextForCurrentThread, createEntity, isSample, links, primitiveType, setPrimitiveType, typeString
```

I want to know what is this problem?, this warning doesn't prevent me to upload the app.

I have found a lot of threads with same problems but all of them are aboud the Facebook framework, but I don't have that framework.

I have had no problems before this release and I haven't added new frameworks, only new code written by me.

I have Xcode5 and the app is build for iOS7.

Comment: Are these warnings informing you but you are still able to submit the app, or are these errors preventing you from uploading the app?

Comment: Can you provide more details about what your app is about ?

Comment: @Rich this warning doesn't prevent me to upload the app

Comment: If you can't validate your app, you can't upload it to iTunes Connect. Ever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its just warnings from a static analyser Apple/the upload process runs on your code. I believe it just checks for various private selector names. If you haven't done anything you shouldn't in your own code you should be fine. I've had it a few times before in my own apps.

Comment: But is a risk submitting the ap with a warning?

Comment: Nope, it'll be fine. More info on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199640/do-build-warnings-affect-the-ios-app-store-approval-process).

Comment: I summited the app, I will let you know what happen after that

Comment: @Gabox Was everything fine in the end?

Comment: How was this an accepted answer? It's not a warning he's receiving; it's an error that prevents uploading the app to the App Store. Your "solution" has no steps to it. @Gabox How did you submit the app with this error? I doubt you did. What was the point of your question?

Comment: @JamesBush you do realise things might have changed in the almost 3.5 years since this question was asked never mind the 3 (4) major versions of Xcode since then... Also made you should [read all the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199640/do-build-warnings-affect-the-ios-app-store-approval-process) before making grand statements!

Comment: There are no warnings in the App Distribution process—only errors.

Comment: @Rich It wasn't a grand statement to point out that an answer wasn't provided, which becomes obvious to anyone the second they find out what the answer to the problem really is (as I did). The two are different in every conceivable way you can hardly believe someone proffered it to begin with, let alone someone accepted it. This has a contrived feel to it. A nonsensical answer to a question posed by someone who contradicted themselves as to the extent of the problem.